# Application of the inverse Fourier Theorem

Tags: fourier-transform

There is a certain function $S_n(x)=\frac{\sin x \sin nx}{x^2}$ for $x\neq 0$, and $S_n(0)=n$. There is another function $T_n$, such that $\widehat{T_n}=4S_n$, where $\widehat{\cdot}$ is the Fourier transform operator. We can assume that $S_n\in L_1$. Everything is defined on $\mathbb{R}$. The question asks to find the Fourier transform $\widehat{S}_n(\eta)$. The answer is apparently $\widehat{S}_n=\frac{\pi}{2} T_n$. This is how I proceeded:

$$\int_\mathbb{R}e^{-inx}T_n(x)dx=\widehat{T}_n=4S_n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_\mathbb{R}e^{in\xi}\widehat{S}_n(\xi)d\xi.$$

The problem is that on the right-hand side we have $e^{in\xi}$ and on the left-hand side we have $e^{-inx}$. If the signs were the same we could conclude immediately. Can I get some help on how to proceed? Is there some property of Fourier transforms that I am not aware of?

Update:
This is the solution we have in the book, but I don't understand where the first equality comes from.

[image]

Comment: It would be easy to make the signs the same. $\xi$ is a dummy variable. Set $x = -\xi$. However, this will not exactly help you. You cannot conclude in general that because two integrals are equal, their kernels are equal. Instead, you need to use this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem

Comment: @kevinkayaks Could you show how to use it? We are told in the hint to use, but I don't understand how.

Comment: You just multiply your equation by $e^{-i n y}$ then sum over $n$. This will provide a  sum over a kronecker delta which you can easily evaluate.

Comment: @kevinkayaks I still have a sign issue. Do you mind writing the solution out as an answer?

Comment: You can easily change the sign with a u substitution

Comment: Also note $S_n(-x)=S_n(x)$

Comment: The sign issue you mention is the reason why in the solution you get $-\mathrm{Id}$ and not just the identity. The other results that you have to use is the fact that Fourier transforms sends product into convolutions (and vice versa).